# Years of hardship has/have . .

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm wondering if "Years of hardship" takes a singular or plural verb:

> Years of hardship has/have taken a toll on his health.

> Twenty years of hardship has/have taken a toll on his health.

Comment: Birds of a feather flock together.

Comment: Some say nouns denoting time or money take singular verbs.

Comment: Years of hard labor has made their farm one of the finest in that part of the State.

https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=K91fAAAAMAAJ&q=%22+years+of+hard+labor+has%22&dq=%22+years+of+hard+labor+has%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0-r6w243zAhXGwosBHT5oDLI4HhDoAXoECAoQAg

Comment: Read the latest quoted sentence, please.

Comment: You have provided another example but not "the rule".

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131960/verbs-that-follow-an-amount-of-time-singular-or-plural

Comment: Where is **the rule**??

Comment: "The amount of time is a single unit even though it is expressed by describing an aggregated number of units of time. **When that amount is the subject of the sentence or clause, it takes a singular verb.**"

Comment: Where is the authority who said that? Even the ELU answers don't cite one.

Comment: Where is your authority then? Can't you contribute something more substantial?

Comment: @Lambie Here's a rule I found in Practical English Usage by Michael Swan. Its scope covers more than just time expressions: "_When we talk about amounts and quantities we usually use singular determiners, verbs and pronouns, even if the noun is plural._"

Comment: We could find any number of written examples for both pluralities. Here's [*the child has no friends because **years of illness has given her** a “scary” look*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22years+of+illness+has+given%22), for example. I don't think it really matters what any specific "authorities" say - both forms occur (but strictly literal *Years of drought **are** a plural subject here* is definitely more common).

Comment: Improvements to the question belong in the question, not in the comments, since those can be removed at any time.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker, I have generally heard only a plural verb with the first construction ("years of hardship have . . .") but either with the second ("twenty years of hardship has/have . . ."). Perhaps that's because the explicit number ("twenty") makes it sound more like a definite quantity.

Answer (score 1):

**Have**.

The prepositional phrase "of hardship" should be ignored in determining the verb to use.  The verb needs to agree with the subject "years".